# how to prevent video playing in landscape mode in android device?

Tags: android, video, landscape

I am working as a android developer and while testing my app in Samsung I found something.
When I am capturing any video in my Samsung device with portrait mode, and then playing it in a video view, it will display with the wrong orientation. Portrait video will play with landscape orientation. I think it is rotating the video 90 degree left. Please guide us to solve this problem.

Video is played in the correct orientation in devices from other manufactures like Google Nexus or Micromax. It is played in the correct orientation but in Samsung the portrait video orientation is not proper.